# How to assign Rails model column by symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def load_data(data)
    self.foo = data[:foo] if data.has_key?(:foo)
    self.bar = data[:bar] if data.has_key?(:bar)
    self.moo = data[:moo] if data.has_key?(:moo)
    self.save
  end
end
```

I want to write the method like this:

```
[:foo, :bar, :moo].each do |sym|
    # need some trick here
    self.sym = data[sym] if data.has_key?(sym)
end
```

Of course this method doesn't work, how can I assign a value to a Model column by using a symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vee's answer is correct for the general case, but since this is Rails and ActiveRecord, you can take some nice shortcuts:

```
def load_data(data)
  update_attributes data.slice(:foo, :bar:, :moo)
end
```

This works because `data.slice` filters your `data` hash to just the given keys, and then `update_attributes` will set those values in your model and invoke `#save`. When the keys aren't present, they aren't written, so you don't need to check and assign each key separately.

If you don't care about filtering the inbound data and simply assigning the keys given to the model, then just `update_attributes data` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `send`:

```
[:foo, :bar, :moo].each do |sym|
    # need some trick here
    send "#{sym}=", data[sym] if data.has_key?(sym)
end
```